# Want to write my own program. Need to ask if similar programs exist

Tags: support, stack-overflow, scope

Can I ask people if a similar program already exists?   If not, any ideas where to ask?  It is something that people might use a certain vocabulary for, but maybe I don't know that vocabulary, so it is kind of hard to search for it.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a programming related program, like a parser, a library or some other development tool?

If it is, it should be fine on SO.

Otherwise, I would say Superuser.com is the right choice.

Comment: Nope - not a programming related program.  I will try Superuser.

Comment: @sqlnoob: unless it's particularly enterprise-IT related (in which case ask on Server Fault) or a web application (in which case there's [a proposed site on the way](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications), but nothing live yet) or an application for iPhone, Android, or other gadget (in which case there's [a proposed site on the way](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) but...)